# Tournament hand not triggering (Chaos on deponia / Switch)

Tags: deponia

I'm playing "Chaos on Deponia" on Switch, and I already consulted a walkthrough, but it doesn't work.

So I went to join the `Unorganized Crime` and shaved `Donnas Cat` which got me into the dialog where she wants to throw me to the shark. Since none of the options worked, I finally used `Go ahead`, which should, according to the walkthrough, convince Donna that I'm worthy to join, but this didn't happen and consequently I didn't get the "Tournament Hand`, or I'm looking in the wrong place.
According to the walkthrough I should now

> Get through the bridge and take the Tournament Hand

but I don't know which bridge is meant. I don't see such a bridge. When I go back to Donna there is no dialog anymore, and now I'm stuck. Either there is something I'm doing wrong, or this is a bug.

I certainly don't want to replay the full game, as it autosaves and I can't go back.